# Azure SQL Server vs Table Storage performance

Tags: azure-sql-database, azure-table-storage

I have read a lot about the performance for Azure Table Storage. My take away is , if only using partionkey Azure Table Storage is lightning fast. To test it I created two scenarios.

A SQL server on a basic price tier with 13 million rows. All columns are indexed.
A table storage with 120000 rows.
Both with same entity:

```
public class Item
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Path { get; set; }

    public bool Deleted { get; set; }

    public int JobId { get; set; }

    public DateTime Started { get; set; }

    public int DurationInMS { get; set; }

    public int Status { get; set; }
}
```

When I query the SQL server it returns 706326 rows in 28 seconds.

When I query table storage on the partion key it returns 100000 rows in 36,5 seconds.

I would expect table storage to be much faster. Specially because the table has much less data, and I am only using the partion key. Is SQL server really faster? I am surprised because of most articles stating Table Storage is so fast.

SQL Server query EF:

```
 var db = new CleanupDB(_config.DBConnection);

 var sw = new Stopwatch();
 sw.Start();
 var dd = db.Items.Where(p => p.JobId == 4).ToList();
 sw.Stop();
 var ms = sw.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds;
```

Table storage query:

```
 CloudTable table = tableClient.GetTableReference("items");

 var q = from s in table.CreateQuery<ItemItemEntity>()
 where s.PartitionKey == "1"
 select s.JobId;

 var sw = new Stopwatch();
 sw.Start();
 var ee = q.ToList();
 sw.Stop();
 var ms = sw.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds;
```

Any of you have other experience? I am missing something here or might SQL server just be faster? I think this specific scenario should favor Table Storage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just for azure table storage(I'm not familiar with azure sql), it's not a good practice to query table storage by only using `partition_key` and it will execute `partition scan` which will take a little more time.

For azure table query, the performance from good to bad is: Point Query -> Range Query -> Partition Scan -> Table Scan.

The details are as below(you can also find it from this [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/tables/table-storage-design-for-query#how-your-choice-of-partitionkey-and-rowkey-impacts-query-performance)):

**Point Query:** A Point Query is the most efficient lookup to use and is recommended to be used for high-volume lookups or lookups requiring lowest latency. Such a query can use the indexes to locate an individual entity very efficiently by specifying both the PartitionKey and RowKey values. For example: $filter=(PartitionKey eq 'Sales') and (RowKey eq '2')

**Range Query:** It uses the PartitionKey and filters on a range of RowKey values to return more than one entity. The PartitionKey value identifies a specific partition, and the RowKey values identify a subset of the entities in that partition. For example: $filter=PartitionKey eq 'Sales' and RowKey ge 'S' and RowKey lt 'T'

**Partition Scan:** It uses the PartitionKey and filters on another non-key property and that may return more than one entity. The PartitionKey value identifies a specific partition, and the property values select for a subset of the entities in that partition. For example: $filter=PartitionKey eq 'Sales' and LastName eq 'Smith'

**Table Scan:** It does not include the PartitionKey and is very inefficient because it searches all of the partitions that make up your table in turn for any matching entities. It will perform a table scan regardless of whether or not your filter uses the RowKey. For example: $filter=LastName eq 'Jones'

Comment: But what if you need all the rows in a given partition? Thats is my scenario. Doing it from a SQL server with over 100 times more data it takes 28 secs. With TS much slower.

Comment: As per I mentioned, you should try use Range Query if you want to get all the rows in a given partition(it would be faster than just use partition key only). You need to design your azure table storage according to this article: [Table design patterns](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/tables/table-storage-design-patterns). And I also try to find some docs which should prove that the table storage is faster, but no good luck. If you have such docs, you can add it to your issues. Thanks.